# Escaping in regex expression python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, regex-group, regex-greedy

I'm looking to extract the id tag from the following field of data:

```
{"purchased_at":"2020-04-21T05:55:30.000Z","product_desc":"Garnier 2019 Shampoo","onhold":{"copyright":true,"country_codes":["ABC"],"scope":"poss"},"id":"8745485"}
```

The regex I'm using breaks when this field is encountered as I'm using `'"id":\s*"(.*?)"'`.

Because, only some fields have such extra onhold tag:

```
{"purchased_at":"2020-04-21T05:55:30.000Z","product_desc":"All clear 2019 \n ","id":"7462764"}
```

The whole file is of the form:

```
{"info":[{"purchased_at":"","product_desc":"","id":""}{..}]}
```

Comment: This looks like JSON, you should use the `json` module, not regex.

Comment: And the regex question is unclear. What exactly do you mean by "breaks"?

Comment: @mkrieger1 ID = re.search(id_pattern, match.group(0)) when I try this I get Nonetype has no group object.

Answer (score 1):

You can import `json` library in order to extract the desired value for the key (`id`), rather than using a regular expression :

```
import json
str = '{"purchased_at":"2020-04-21T05:55:30.000Z","product_desc":"Garnier 2019 Shampoo","onhold":{"copyright":true,"country_codes":["ABC"],"scope":"poss"},"id":"8745485"}'

js = json.loads(str)

for i in js:
      if i == 'id':
            print(js[i])

>>>
8745485
```

**Update** : If you need to find out by using methods related with regular expression, then using `search` function of `re` library with proper pattern might help :

```
import re
str = '{"purchased_at":"2020-04-21T05:55:30.000Z","product_desc":"Garnier 2019 Shampoo","onhold":{"copyright":true,"country_codes":["ABC"],"scope":"poss"},"id":"8745485"}'

s = re.search('id":"(.+?)"', str)

if s:
    print( s.group(1) )

>>>
8745485
```

Comment: I understand. But I'm looking for a regex answer!

Comment: It needs to be said again: *don't* use regex for this.

Comment: then, the first part is OK, and I should delete the **update** part, do you mean this @tripleee ?

Comment: Nah, just trying to tell the OP that they definitely don't want what they insist that they want.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `findall` method in `re` module to extract data.

```py
import re
line='{"purchased_at":"2020-04-21T05:55:30.000Z","product_desc":"Garnier 2019 Shampoo","onhold":{"copyright":true,"country_codes":["ABC"],"scope":"poss"},"id":"8745485"}'
print(re.findall('"id":\s*"(.*?)"',line))
```

**Output**

```
['8745485']
```